# Getting error on loading in angular2 RC4: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading

Tags: angular

I am getting the following exception when the application is loading on the browser. Please find the config files and error details below.

Error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
    http://localhost:59856/node_modules/@angular/core/index.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
    localhost/:17 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:59856/node_modules/@angular/core/index.js
            at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:769:30)
            at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:356:38)
            at Zone.runTask (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:256:48)
            at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:423:34)
        Error loading http://localhost:59856/node_modules/@angular/core/index.js as "@angular/core" from http://localhost:59856/app/main.js(anonymous function) @ localhost/:17
    http://localhost:59856/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
    http://localhost:59856/styles.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Package.json

```
      {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "name": "ngcorecontacts",
      "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "typings install",
        "typings": "typings"
      },
      "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
        "tslint": "^3.7.4",
        "typescript": "^1.8.10",
        "typings": "^1.0.4"
    },
    "repository": {}
```

In Systemjs.Config.js

```
 /**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };

    var packageNames = [
      '@angular/common',
      '@angular/compiler',
      '@angular/core',
      '@angular/forms',
      '@angular/http',
      '@angular/platform-browser',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
      '@angular/router'
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form 
    // '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

tsconfig.json

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

What is it I am missing here?

Comment: Which version you are trying - RC1 or RC4? You package.json pointing to 2.0.0-rc.1

Comment: Updated the config entries, still facing the same issue, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

You can not import the node_modules from wwwroot, but you have to copy the bundles in a destination folder in wwwroot, for example by gulp, and then import them from there by systemjs.config.js
The working solution of AspNet core with Angular2-RC4, I have uploaded as zip file in [github](https://github.com/snkrishnan1/Angular2RC4/blob/master/Angular2RC4.zip)

Answer (score 3):

this is because you are loading your application from `appScripts` as pointed here:

`"outDir": "../wwwroot/appScripts/",` 
but your are referring to `app` in your system config.

quick fix would be to remove the `outDir` from `tsconfig.json` and run the application. Ideally you should use @angular-cli for build. look [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

Comment: Updated the config entries, still facing the same issue, any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: In plunker it works fine, same config settings and other components when placed in Visual studio IDE (AspNet Core RC2), on running the application I am getting this error. Please download zip file from the Github URL, WebApplication1.zip file from github.com/snkrishnan1/Angular2RC4. In this github repo, I have used the same config from the Quickstart tutorials but getting the above mentioned errors. Do you have any working solution built on AspNet Core RC2  with Angular2 RC4 ?